# SKMaps module not found when installing as a CocoaPods dependency

Tags: cocoapods, skmaps

I can't get the SKMaps module to resolve when installing it as a Cocoapods dependency.

When importing:

```
import SKMaps
```

I get the following error: `No such module 'SKMaps'`. My Podfile is as follows:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'

target 'TestSpace' do
use_frameworks!

pod 'ScoutMaps-iOS-SDK'

end
```

I have run `pod install`, and it succeeded. As far as I understand a bridging header should not be necessary when installing a Cocoapods-dependency when declaring `use_frameworks!`.

*More details:*

I have opened the .xcworkspace generated by `pod install`. I don't understand all the details of the Cocoapods framework, but at the end of `Pods-TestSpace-frameworks.sh` there is a section at the end that only appears if I add other dependencies.

```
if [[ "$CONFIGURATION" == "Debug" ]]; then 
  install_framework "Pods-TestSpace/OtherDependency.framework"
fi
if [[ "$CONFIGURATION" == "Release" ]]; then
  install_framework "Pods-TestSpace/OtherDependency.framework"
fi
```

I don't know if that is just a matter of the dependency using a different configuration type, or if it's an indication of something being wrong.

Also, the version of the `ScoutMaps-iOS-SDK` being downloaded/installed is `2.5.1`.

Comment: Checking with Scout developers

Comment: Did you get any response on this? Is there something like an archetype project with an example of how to set it up correctly?

Comment: Unfortunately, no answer yet, but it's on the list. The dev team is fully booked with the new release and the enterprise requests.

Comment: As the current SKMaps does not support modules- that's the reason why it's not working. SKMaps 3.0 will work with this- should be released soon

Answer (score 0):

After running pod install, you'll need to close the Xcode project and then open the newly generated .xcworkspace file.

Comment: Yes, I have taken this step, so that's not the issue.

Comment: Did you managed to find a solution ? I kind of have the same type of issues actually